# Website Links on Mobile Devices - Opening Native Applications or Redirecting to App Store if Uninstalled

Tags: javascript, html, web

How can you let social media links (this could actually be generalized to any link to a mobile application) on your website direct mobile devices either to the corresponding native application (say, Facebook, for example) OR (if the application is not installed) to the app store page on which the app is offered? I'm mainly concerned with doing this with Apple's iOS 11.

Comment: This can be handled from your server side to redirect the devices to the appropriate URLs

Comment: Yes, but how do I check to see which URL to direct them to prior to directing them to a new page? Once you execute the redirection, the document is removed from the window, which I assume means you can't direct them to an invalid page and then to a valid page using javascript. My problem is that I need to check whether an app is installed on the device before I can properly redirect them, but I don't think you can do that.